# Output for every register ina SQL query

Tags: sql, database

Is it possible to get an output like this from a SQL query?

Example query:

```sql
SELECT user 
FROM users 
WHERE user IN (user1, user2, user3)
```

Pretending output:

```
true, false, true
```

The output doesn't need to be true or false, just a reference that the registers exists in the database. Is it possible to do it? Thank you for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use case when statement